# dereferencing causes crash, even for non-NULL pointer, why?

Tags: c++

I tried to scan the whole process, but it crashed. I do not understand why that happened. What's another equivalent but safer way to do so?

```
void searchAddrByValue(const int value) {
    int *p = (int *)0x00FFFFFF;
    while ((int *)0x0FFFFFFF >= p) {
        if(value == *p)
            fprintf(filePointer, "Addr:%p -- Val:%d\n", p, *p);
        ++p;
    }
    display(L"Finished");
}
```

Comment: ... Because you don't own those memory addresses.

Comment: If you didn't use `new` or `malloc` to allocate memory, don't expect to be able to dereference a pointer and get predictable behavior.

Comment: Thank you!! Maybe I use some system API instead such as ReadProcessMemory... do you think it can solve this issue?

Comment: `ReadProcessMemory()` (in the windows API) also fails if used to read an area of memory that is not accessible to your program.    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Crashing when trying to read inaccessible memory is a feature, not a bug -- it gives you the chance to debug your program, and (more importantly) prevents malicious programs from reading data that they are not meant to have access to.

Comment: @Jeremy: No, address translation is what prevents malicious programs from reading memory they don't own.  The fact that reading a non-existent address is purely to prevent you from overlooking the bug, and not related to process isolation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search all memory inside your process, you should first use `VirtualQueryEx` to find out which pages are valid addresses, and then search inside readable pages.

The MSDN article on [Managing Virtual Memory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810627.aspx) outlines how to walk the address ranges in your process address space.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through all properly allocated memory you can use VirtualQueryEx, ensure the region's state is MEM_COMMIT and the protection is not PAGE_NOACCESS, before doing anything else.  If you want to ReadProcessMemory() each region into a local buffer you can certainly do that, just replace the console output in this code with the code you want to execute on each region:

```cpp
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
unsigned char* addr = 0;

HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
{
    if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS)
    {
        std::cout << "base : 0x" << std::hex << mbi.BaseAddress << " end : 0x" << std::hex << (uintptr_t)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize << "\n";
    }
    addr += mbi.RegionSize;
}

CloseHandle(hProc);
```

This code will print out the start and end address of each region

Make sure you run as admin and you may also want to check for PAGE_GUARD as well, but I haven't run into that being a problem.